# How can I append append paginated pages to tables in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, pagination

I'm loading query data from a MySQL server into multiple tables.  There can be thousands of rows in each table, so I'm trying to setup pagination with a "load more" button at the bottom of each table.

Let's say each table initially displays the first 100 rows of data.  Is there a simple way to implement a button which will append the next page of query data to the currently selected table?

Answer (score 0):

Always set up your pagination to page 1 `p.page(1)` and change dinamically (i.e. url argument) the number of rows `page_range`, taking into account this number should be lower than the total number of records `p.count`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

Edit note: I should warn you that you are destroying the pagination concept totally, like fancy infinite pagination, and some web browsers may die trying to show too much HTML.